# How to save google JsonObject field into dynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gson, amazon-dynamodb, json

I have json request like below.

```
{  
 "color":"red",
 "type":"publish",
 "events":{  
   "some":"Yes",
   "collection":[  
      {  
         "key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"
     },
     {  
        "key3":"value3",
        "key4":"value4"
     }
   ],
   "nestedObject":{  
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6"
    }
  }
```

}

I have create POJO class with color as String, type as string, and events as JsonObject. Value of events field can be any value of json format. So I created it as JsonObject. My question is how can I store events into the data base. For dynamo we can use @DynamoDBDocument annotation to marshal other object into current POJO. Now I cant use because we have to annotate to the class to marshall. In this case JsonObject is out of my scope to annotate. Is there any other way to store JsonObject into dynamo?

Comment: Can the events object not also be a POJO? If so, this seems like a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: No I cant create POJO for events because it can have any fields. One client sends x,y,z. other client sends a,b,c. It should be generic to access any json  format value.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the WithJSON Method to save the string representation

```html
String jsonDoc = json.toString();
Item item = new Item()
    .withPrimaryKey("pid", "Test")
    .withJSON("doc", jsonDoc);

table.putItem(item);
```

You can also refer to the following AWS documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#PutDocumentAPIJava

Comment: I am using Dynamodb mapper class to do CRUS operation on dynamo.